# Why did my question switch to Community Wiki?

Tags: support, specific-question, community-wiki

Why is it that my question, [Is this WPF ProgressBar Odd render behaviour a Bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1852647/is-this-wpf-progressbar-odd-render-behaviour-a-bug) now community wiki?

What happened to set it off like that? Was it something I did?

Comment: This should be a FAQ.

Answer (score 4):

Your post was made [Community Wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts-on-stack-overflow/11741#11741) because you edited it eight times. I count 9, but I don't think the Rollback counts.